# Twig-Codeigniter: Html contents not showing

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twig

I don't know what i did wrong but my contents inside included files don't show but are visible when trying to see its source code. I am using Codeigniter3 with Twig-php as a template library. I have these following directories when my templates are located:

`/twig ( twig path)
 /_includes ( partial templates)
 /_layouts ( layouts templates)
 /contents
  /mobile (main templates)`

in my layouts path i have base.html. I also extended my index page to the main layout. My index page also have some included files from twig/_includes , header and footer.

Index page :

```
{% extends _layout %} 

{% block content %}

{% include twig.widget('_default-header') %}

index

{% include twig.widget('_default-footer') %}


{% endblock %}
```

Layout:

```
{# main layout #}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<base href="{{ base_url () }}"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ base_url () }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/mobile.css">
{{ link_tag }}
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="OnKoz">
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/+Onkoz"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="language" content="en"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="Category" content="chat">
</head>

<body style="margin-bottom:45px;" id="t">

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

header:

```
<!-- Fixed header navbar --> 

<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top container" role="banner" style="border-top: 3px solid #FB9795;"> 

      <div class="container"> 

       <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> 
        <a href="/" title="free chat site online" class="navbar-brand"> {{ site.name }}</a> 
       </div> 

       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right"> 
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav dropdown-menu"> {{ base_url() }}
        <li><a href="{{ base_url() }}"> <i class="icon-home"></i> Home </a></li> 
      <li><a href="{{ base_url() }}user/member"><i class="icon-key"></i> Login</a></li> 
      <li><a href="{{ base_url() }}user/signup_form"><i class="icon-star"></i> Sign up</a></li> 
      <li><a href=" {{ base_url() }}about/contact"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse --> 



      </div> 
    <!--/.container --> 

     </header>
```

Footer:

```
<footer class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom container" role="banner" style="border-top: 3px solid #FB9795;">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="{{ base_url() }}" title="free chat site online" class="navbar-brand" id=''>
<img alt="Chatiw" src="/images/favicon.png" id="brand_image"> OnKoz
</a>
<p class="navbar-text" id="footer_years">{{ fn.auto_copyright(2017) }} ©  </p>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li>
<a href="{{ base_url() }}about/faq" target='_blank' title="FAQ">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign'></i> FAQ </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="{{ base_url() }}about/safety_tips" target='_blank' title="Safety Tips">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign'></i> Safety Tips </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="{{ base_url() }}about/privacy_policy" target='_blank' title="Privacy Policy">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></i> Privacy Policy </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="{{ base_url() }}about/contact" target='_blank' title="Contact us">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></i> Contact us
</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe'></i> Language <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="{{ base_url() }}?lang=en/" title="English"><img src="{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/english.png" alt="English"> English</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.chatiw.uk/" title="English UK"><img src="{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/english.png" alt="English UK"> English UK</a></li>
<li><a href='{{ base_url() }}?lang=fr/' title='French'><img src='{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/french.png' alt='French'> French</a></li>
<li><a href='{{ base_url() }}?lang=de/' title='Germany'><img src='{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/german.png' alt='Germany'> Germany</a></li>
<li><a href='{{ base_url() }}?lang=es/' title='Spanish'><img src='{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/spanish.png' alt='Spanish'> Spanish</a></li>
<li><a href='{{ base_url() }}?lang=it/' title='Italian'><img src='{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/italian.png' alt='Italian'> Italian</a></li>
<li><a href='{{ base_url() }}?lang=ru/' title='Russian'><img src='{{ base_url() }}assets/images/lang/russian.png' alt='Russian'> Russian</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Main
Here is the link to the webpage in question [OnKoz](http://onkoz.ga) . As you can see , only the index word is displayed.
Update: Sorry for posting the links to pastebin

Comment: Please post your code on SO instead of several pastebin links

Comment: Whats `twig.widget`? Is this a custom macro? Or an object you inject?

Comment: It's a method I added to the twig library by kenjis from codeigniter community. It includes files from the include folder

Answer (score 1):

In the http://onkoz.ga//assets/css/mobile.css file, you have

```
.container {
   display: none;
}
```

That's why it's hidden on browser.
Delete `display:none` or change it to

```
.container {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: Well... @Stephane you forgot to wrap your mobile CSS with mediaqueries

Comment: @darkbee I'll wrap my css with media queries.

Comment: @ahmetson Thanks bro, I changed the container's display to block and everything is in order.